# mongoskin, expressjs, req.params only give me the name back

Tags: express, mongoskin

me new in nodejs, since 2 days i've been try to figured out how it work with mongoskin and express but somehow i have no luck.
need someone help. i need to edit the collection.

```
router.get('/edit/:name', function(req, res){
var db = req.db;
var n = req.params;
console.log(n); // will only output the selected name.
if(!n){res.send('not found query')}
else{
   db.collection('uList').find(n, function(err, docs){
       res.json(docs);
   });
  };
});
```

and hier ist my collection:

```
{"_id": ObjectId("1341354563458567845678"), "name": "fritz", "age": 19, "info": "fritz was here"}
{"_id": ObjectId("9676524234861346897543"), "name": "Susi", "age": 21, "info": "Susi was here too"}
```

hier ist my app.js

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var db = mongo.db('mongodb://localhost:27017/sample', {native_parser:true});
```

Output will only give me the name back

```
{"name": "fritz"}
```

many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!!
if someone have problem like i have, try this.

```
db.collection('uList').find(n).toArray(function(err, n){
   res.json(n);
});
```

will get output like this

```
{"_id": ObjectId("9676524234861346897543"), "name": "Susi", "age": 21, "info": "Susi was here too"}
```

thanks .